# looking for a slider module to use in the header

Tags: 7, javascript

what's a good slider for a header in drupal 7 (I would like to have a slider for different content in other blocks/pages of the website, so if the same module could work for both, better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). It is the most used and most flexible and you can create as many as you need.

Comment: Hello @Nigel, I've successfully created a slider with custom content types, a view and the views slider module you recommended me, however I also see the rest of the images,...and it looks [this pretty](http://i.imgur.com/XKWSX.jpg) right now. Any ideas on how could I remove those 3 pictures under the header?

Answer (score -1):

There is an [awesome slider for featured content](http://flowslider.com) in the header called Flow Slider. It's not integrated into drupal but it is very easy to use.